# django update model and preventing full table lock

Tags: django, django-queryset

Im using `django 4.0.0`. I have a model with an `touched` column (`DateTimeField`) to specify when a specific row was "touched" (like the unix command). I want to write a management command that updates this column to `now()` like so

```
MyModel.objects.all().update(touched=now())
```

but the numbers of rows is large and i DON'T want to have a full table lock for this.
 Is there any way to have django update the queryset in multiple batches - **each batch in a DIFFERENT TRANSACTION**? or is there anyway to split my queryset to do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to batch the update you can try sth like this:

```
batch_size = 10
total_rows = queryset.count()
i = 0

while processed_rows < total_rows:
    batch = queryset[i:i+ batch_size]
    batch.update(touched=now())

    i += batch_size
```

or if you want to use django bulk_update with batch option:

```
objs = []
for obj in queryset:
    obj.touched = now()
    objs.append(obj)
MyModel.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['touched'], batch_size=10)
```

NOTE: none of this are recommended and have pretty slow performance for large amount of data. use them with caution.